# Is it possible to format SQL on output into associative array?

Tags: mysql

We have a table.

```
customer         
+----+------+------+-------+
| id | type | name | group |
+----+------+------+-------+
| 1  | boy  | dave | adult |
| 2  | girl | lisa | child |
| 3  | girl | amy  | adult |
| 4  | boy  | ivan | child |
+------------------+-------+
```

If we query this table with

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE type = 'girl'
```

Result output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [type] => girl
            [name] => lisa
            [group] => child
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [type] => girl
            [name] => amy
            [group] => adult
        )
)
```

I would like to receive the output like the following.

```
Array
(
    [girl] => Array
        (
        [child] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => lisa
            )
        [adult] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [name] => amy
            )
        )
)
```

I could manipulate the result with another programming language, but wondered if this is possible with pure SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?  Most of the reporting products I have used have drill down capabilities that could arrange the data like you ask for but from straight SQL i believe Drew is right.

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish less code overall, If it is not possible, I will have to manipulate the result after its returned.

Comment: a language other than SQL (Java, C#, ETC...) would be better at handling your complex data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no SQL has yet been designed to return associative arrays, but I could be wrong!